# how to edit shared folder doc file in ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager

Tags: javascript

my doc file is inside below path

\\90.0.0.99\Documents\upload\test.doc

so how can i am able to edit this file using `ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager`

code sample using in my code:

```
function edit() {
    ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument(
        \\90.0.0.99\Documents\upload\test.doc",errorCallback
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN USE THIS CODE TO SOLVE PROBLEM:

```
  ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument("https:\\90.0.0.99\Documents\upload\test.doc", "/", protocolInstallMessage);
```

or

```
ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument("\\90.0.0.99\Documents\upload\test.doc");
```

i hope help you.